# SuperFastHash returns different values for the same string

Tags: c, hash

I'm trying to use SuperFastHash in a small project, and I can't seem to understand why it gives different hashes for the same string. It only outputs the same hash if both the pointer and the string are the same. Any ideas? Code to prove this is below.

```
// SuperFastHash, taken from http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#undef get16bits
#if (defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__i386__)) || defined(__WATCOMC__) \
  || defined(_MSC_VER) || defined (__BORLANDC__) || defined (__TURBOC__)
#define get16bits(d) (*((const uint16_t *) (d)))
#endif

#if !defined (get16bits)
#define get16bits(d) ((((uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[1])) << 8)\
                       +(uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[0]) )
#endif

uint32_t SuperFastHash (const char * data, int len);

int main(void)
{
    char* str = "a\0a";
    printf("%s\n", &str[0]); // a
    printf("%s\n", &str[2]); // a
    printf("%i\n", SuperFastHash(&str[0], 25)); // -1120168156
    printf("%i\n", SuperFastHash(&str[2], 25)); // -280310739
}

uint32_t SuperFastHash (const char * data, int len) {
uint32_t hash = len, tmp;
int rem;

    if (len <= 0 || data == NULL) return 0;

    rem = len & 3;
    len >>= 2;

    /* Main loop */
    for (;len > 0; len--) {
        hash  += get16bits (data);
        tmp    = (get16bits (data+2) << 11) ^ hash;
        hash   = (hash << 16) ^ tmp;
        data  += 2*sizeof (uint16_t);
        hash  += hash >> 11;
    }

    /* Handle end cases */
    switch (rem) {
        case 3: hash += get16bits (data);
                hash ^= hash << 16;
                hash ^= ((signed char)data[sizeof (uint16_t)]) << 18;
                hash += hash >> 11;
                break;
        case 2: hash += get16bits (data);
                hash ^= hash << 11;
                hash += hash >> 17;
                break;
        case 1: hash += (signed char)*data;
                hash ^= hash << 10;
                hash += hash >> 1;
    }

    /* Force "avalanching" of final 127 bits */
    hash ^= hash << 3;
    hash += hash >> 5;
    hash ^= hash << 4;
    hash += hash >> 17;
    hash ^= hash << 25;
    hash += hash >> 6;

    return hash;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `len` argument (25) exceeds the string size which is probably meant to be 1. The memory layout of `char* str = "a\0a"` is `{ 'a', 0, 'a', 0 }` after that four chars, it's undefined and most likely not 23 times the same value (which would of course lead to equal hash values). The `SuperFastHash` function ignores the string terminator, it evaluates the amount of chars you define by the `len` argument.

As to see that the function works properly, try for instance:

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *buf = "abc\0abc";
    assert(SuperFastHash(&buf[0], 3) == SuperFastHash(&buf[4], 3));
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a one-char string and you're hashing 25 characters of that string.  So it reads your character and NULL byte, then 23 characters of whatever happens to lie beyond.